# Print little or big endianness in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I want to check the endianness of my computer in an assembly program ( 8086 ) and to print it.

I know what endianness is and how you find it. It is about the way data is stored in memory. For eg if you store 1234 it will be stored 3412 ( little ) or 1234 ( big ). But i don't know how to do it in assembly language. I'm thinking about storing something in memory than load it and compare it with the original. It should be exactly as the theory says. If i store 1234 i will load it as 3412 or 1234.
I have a problem when i'm trying to create an if statement.

```
litte db "little$" 
big db "big$"  

mov ax, var1
cmp ax, var2
je equal
jmp notequal


equal:
lea dx, big
notequal:
lea dx, little
```

I expect it to print little or big, but no matter what values i put in var1 and var 2 it always prints little, because somehow the code is executed line by line. Shouldn't it go to only one label, "equal" or "notequal"?
I want something like:

```
if var1==var2
print big
else
print little
```

Answer (score 3):

This segment will *always* print "little" since, even if you begin execution at `equal`, it will carry on through `notequal`:

```
equal:
    lea dx, big
notequal:
    lea dx, little
```

What you would need is something like:

```
equal:
    lea dx, big
    jmp done
notequal:
    lea dx, little
done:
    ; carry on
```

Additionally, you should store the word `1234h` into some memory location `y`, then read the *byte* back from that same location.

If `12h` then you are big-endian. The value `34h` means little-endian.

Anything else means you have a memory problem :-)

By the way, I'm pretty certain all x86 CPUs are little-endian so, if you're writing this in x86 assembly language, you probably don't *need* to check.

---

By way of example, you can use [Coding Ground](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php) with the following code to see it in action:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov  ax, 0x1234        ; load up 1234 hex
    mov  [myword], ax      ; store that word to memory
    mov  al, [myword]      ; get first byte of that
    cmp  al, 0x12          ; 12 means big endian
    je   big
little:
    mov  edx, l_len        ; prepare for little message
    mov  ecx, l_msg
    jmp  print
big:
    mov  edx, b_len        ; prepare for little message
    mov  ecx, b_msg

print:
    mov  ebx, 1            ; file handle 1 = stdout
    mov  eax, 4            ; 'syswrite' function call
    int  0x80

    mov  eax, 1            ; 'exit' function call
    int  0x80

section .data

myword   dw   0

l_msg    db   'Little endian', 0xa
l_len    equ  $ - l_msg

b_msg    db   'Big endian', 0xa
b_len    equ  $ - b_msg
```

The output window shows, as expected:

```
$ nasm -f elf *.asm; ld -m elf_i386 -s -o demo *.o
$ demo
Little endian
```

Comment: And how can i store for eg. 1234h in memory. Does this counts as storing in memory: ```mem dw ? ``` ; ```mov bx, var1``` ; ```mov mem, bx``` .  Is it storing the value from  var1 into mem as 3412h ?

Comment: Yes, every x86 is always little-endian.  Unlike MIPS or some other ISAs, there's no config bit in a MSR or anything that lets you set endianness with SW.  x86's main reason for existence is binary compatibility so I don't think any vendor has ever added such a thing to any x86-compatible.  Having to support unaligned loads perhaps makes bi-endian hardware more difficult.  I couldn't imagine an x86 that *only* ran big-endian.  Then it couldn't run x86 software, so why burden yourself with all of x86's warts?  Not to mention needing to license patents or something.